# Mirroring remote Git repositories, including sub-repositories fetched with scripts

Tags: git, docker, yocto, mbed, mirroring

In product development, one should always be able to re-build some earlier version of software. In traditional software development, where everything was developed in-house, it was easy, as everything was stored in own repository. But, nowadays, when e.g. Docker is used, it relies on multiple external sources in its build scripts.

This is a problem, when an older release is being built, as it needs also older external components. Sometimes older versions of those external components are not available any more.

In very small projects, it is easy to mirror external components into internal repositories, by hand, and modify build scripts to use these internal repositories. But in larger projects, it becomes practically impossible.

How have you managed to mirror all dependencies of e.g. Docker, Yocto or MBed OS build into internal repositories? These dependencies are usually Git repositories, but in Yocto builds, they are often just references to individual source file packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yocto provides possibility to build everything offline. Please look on "Replicating a Build Offline" chapter of [yocto manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#replicating-a-build-offline).
Once you downloaded all sources you can build it locally.

Comment: @Kalle, if you need any additional info on this subject I'll add to my answer, just let me know. If it clearly answers your question, could you please mark it accepted? Thanks

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for this for the Yocto. However, it is not very practical way, as it requires copying contents of the downloads-directory. This can be done for single build, but if (and when) every build should be made offline capable, it consumes so huge amount of disk space, that it becomes unreasonable. Thus I am searching for a way for mirroring contents before they land to downloads-directory.

Comment: @Kalle you can use downloads-directory or make a patch for the each required receipt to use local repository. Second way is time consuming, but you are really independent. I think using of downloads-directory on network share is a compromise.

Comment: Yes, this works, somehow. However, I'm searching for a solution, which would work for all these needs, not just for Yocto - it is the smallest pain.